# Avoid loop while using curve fitting tool in matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have a `70 x 345600` matrix say `data_in`. Each of its columns is a sample of data at 70 time-steps.
I am training this data by fitting a curve to it using the following loop.

```
output = zeros(30,345600);
for i = 1:345600
    ft_ = fittype('linearinterp') %// I am using a proper model
    targets = data_in(:,i);
    inputs = (1:70)';
    cf_  = fit(inputs,targets,ft_);
    output(:,i) = cf_(71:100);
end
```

Currently with loop it takes about an hour and 20 minutes. Is there a way to speed up this code

Comment: This isn't a solution but just a little optimization... By adding a additional `targets2 = data_in(:,i+172800);` You would be able to half the number of loops nesseccary. Also your definition of `ft_` and `inputs` are fixxed, meaning you should do them outside of the loop further reducing the time needed. Because you wouldn't overwrite them in each loop with the same values again...

Comment: @TheMinion putting declaration of `ft_` and inputs outside the loop may reduce time. But, adding additional targets and then using the `fit` function again will result in the same no. of calls to `fit` . Hence complexity will remain the same

Comment: This looks like a job for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).